# get_post_gallery_images returns thumbs . I want full size

Tags: images, gallery

I have the following code on my site.

```
<?php // image gallery content 
if( has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) ) {                     
    $gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post->ID );


    $image_list = '<ul id="cfImageGallery">';                       
    foreach( $gallery as $image ) {// Loop through each image in each gallery
        $image_list .= '<li><img src=" ' . str_replace('-150x150','',$image) . ' " /></li>';
    }
    $image_list .= '</ul>';                     
    echo $image_list;                       
}                         
?>
```

My problem is that get_post_gallery_images returns thumbs files instead of fill size so Im using the str_replace function to solve it.

How can I make to retrieve the full size urls?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working within a template file, this code should work. However, I didn't test it.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery size="full"]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 6):

@tfer77 has given the right answer. I am here explaining it in a more better way.

You need to add `size="full"` attribute to the gallery shortcode in the post content like

`[gallery ids="836,830,829" size="full"]`

Now when you use

```
$gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post->ID );
```

You will get full size images. You can check the same by using the filter `get_post_gallery`

Paste the below code in your theme's functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'get_post_gallery', 'wpse_get_full_size_gallery_images', 10, 3 );
function wpse_get_full_size_gallery_images( $gallery, $post, $galleries ) { 
    var_dump($gallery);
}
```

and the page where you have used `get_post_gallery_images`, you will get a image url as

`http://www.siteurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/eiffel-tower.jpg`

rather than

`http://www.siteurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/eiffel-tower-150x150.jpg`