# Get gallery and product gallery images full size

Tags: loop, plugins, gallery, images

I'm trying to get all gallery images in a while loop of posts (for example a blog page). With the code I'm using right now, I only get the small thumbnail images (150px : 150px). Also I want to get the product gallery images full size (woocommerce). How to do this?

This is what I've done so far and gives me the thumbnail images:

```
 $gallery = get_post_gallery( $theid, false );

       foreach( $gallery['src'] AS $src )
        {
            ?>

            <a href="<?php echo $src; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" class="pp gallery" alt="Gallery image" ></a>

            <?php
        }
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can find a possible answer here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120544/get-post-gallery-images-returns-thumbs-i-want-full-size/120549#120549